# Securing arduino to mosquitto connection with TLS

Tags: ssl, arduino, client, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to secure the connection between the arduino [pubsub](http://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/) client and mosquitto broker (which is running on a public server) over TLS.

Normally(on windows etc), I can publish/subscribe like bellow while giving the certificate files. (certificate and key files are in my working directory).

`mosquitto_pub -h myhost.com -p 8883 -t "/test" -m "your secure message" --cafile ca.crt --cert client.crt --key client.key`

`mosquitto_sub -h myhost.com -p 8883 -t "/test" --cafile ca.crt --cert client.crt --key client.key`

But is there a way to do this in arduino?

Comment: The mosquitto client doesn't run on an arduino, do you mean the pubsub client from here http://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/?

Comment: And which Hardware/Arduino are you using? The Uno for example does not have the memory to run full TLS. Although it is possible that it could be offloaded to the network chip, if using something like a ESP8288.

Comment: I'm using Sam3x8e chip.  Thank you! :)

Comment: @hardillb yeah...  :) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [pubsub](http://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/) MQTT client doesn't support SSL/TLS out of the box. You can try integrating with some light weight SSL/TLS libraries.

Few Embedded SSL Libraries:
https://wolfssl.com/wolfSSL/Products-wolfssl.html
http://www.matrixssl.org/

Or you can opt for [Paho MQTT Client](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/embedded/) - a prebuilt Arduino port of MQTTClient. It supports MQTT V3.1.1, SSL/TLS, QOS-2 Support etc., which are not available in [pubsub](http://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/) client.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there's encryption availabe for normal arduino boards, at least not what I've seen. There are a few workarounds though, either you use another broker without encryption on one side (connected to the arduino) and then encryption on the other end (connected to the public broker).

The other option is to use a board that runs on linux and then call mosquitto commands from arduino code. Here's an example for the intel edison board: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/04/06/using-edison-securely-connect-iot-sensor-to-the-internet-with-mqtt

Comment: Yeah, I also searched around and I could not be able to find a way. :( :( Thanks for the answer! :)